# tweepy user_timeline with pagination returning max of 3200 tweets per twitter user

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I'm using the code from here to scrape the tweets of a few users and export is as a .csv: https://towardsdatascience.com/tweepy-for-beginners-24baf21f2c25

I want to ideally get all the tweets of each user, but it seems to be limited to only the most recent 3200 tweets. Here's the exact code I'm using with trump as an example:

```
ids = ['realDonaldTrump']


def extract_hashtags(hashtag_list):
    final_hashtag = ''
    for hashtag in hashtag_list:
        final_hashtag = final_hashtag + ' ' + hashtag['text']
        
    return final_hashtag.strip()
        
#from https://towardsdatascience.com/tweepy-for-beginners-24baf21f2c25
class TweetMiner(object):

    result_limit    =   20    
    data            =   []
    api             =   False
    
    twitter_keys = { #redacted   }
    
    
    def __init__(self, keys_dict=twitter_keys, api=api, result_limit = 20):
        
        self.twitter_keys = keys_dict
        
        auth = tw.OAuthHandler(keys_dict['consumer_key'], keys_dict['consumer_secret'])
        auth.set_access_token(keys_dict['access_token_key'], keys_dict['access_token_secret'])
        
        self.api = tw.API(auth)
        self.twitter_keys = keys_dict
        
        self.result_limit = result_limit
        

    def mine_user_tweets(self, user,
                         mine_rewteets=False,
                         max_pages=5):

        data           =  []
        last_tweet_id  =  False
        page           =  1
        
        while page <= max_pages:
            if last_tweet_id:
                statuses   =   self.api.user_timeline(screen_name=user,
                                                     count=self.result_limit,
                                                     max_id=last_tweet_id - 1,
                                                     tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                                     include_retweets=True
                                                    )        
            else:
                statuses   =   self.api.user_timeline(screen_name=user,
                                                        count=self.result_limit,
                                                        tweet_mode = 'extended',
                                                        include_retweets=True)
                
            for item in statuses:

                mined = {
                    'tweet_id':        item.id,
                    'name':            item.user.name,
                    'screen_name':     item.user.screen_name,
                    'retweet_count':   item.retweet_count,
                    'text':            item.full_text,
                    'mined_at':        datetime.datetime.now(),
                    'created_at':      item.created_at,
                    #'time_zone':        item._json['time_zone'],
                    'favourite_count': item.favorite_count,
                    'hashtags':        extract_hashtags(item.entities['hashtags']),
                    #'links':           extract_
                    'status_count':    item.user.statuses_count,
                    'location':        item.place,
                    'source_device':   item.source
                }
                
                try:
                    mined['retweet_text'] = item.retweeted_status.full_text
                except:
                    mined['retweet_text'] = 'None'
                try:
                    mined['quote_text'] = item.quoted_status.full_text
                    mined['quote_screen_name'] = status.quoted_status.user.screen_name
                except:
                    mined['quote_text'] = 'None'
                    mined['quote_screen_name'] = 'None'
                
                last_tweet_id = item.id
                data.append(mined)
                
            page += 1
            
        return data
    
#result_limit * max_pages is the no of tweets for each id
miner=TweetMiner(result_limit = 460) #200
counter = 0
counter2 = 0
for id in ids:
    try:
        print("Fetching tweets of " + id+ " now...")
        mined_tweets = miner.mine_user_tweets(user= id, max_pages=460) #100
        mined_tweets_df= pd.DataFrame(mined_tweets)
        
        counter2 = counter2 +1
        #after 40 tries, pause for 15 mins
        if counter2%40==0: #5
            print("Couldn't fetch, sleeping for 15 mins")
            time.sleep(900) #15 minute sleep time
    except:
        print(id, 'is invalid or locked')
    
    if counter>0:
        final_df = pd.concat([final_df, mined_tweets_df], ignore_index = True)
        print("Fetched and added!")
    else:
        final_df = mined_tweets_df
        print("Fetched and added!")
    counter +=1 
    
print(final_df)
final_df.to_csv('tweets.csv', encoding='UTF-8')
```

The number of tweets returned should be 460*460 = 211,600 tweets for each user in ids, but it only returns a total of 3200 tweets per id. Is this limit a strict one built into the API, and if so, is there any way to get more than 3200 tweets per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limit built into the Twitter API. The [user timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) can only return a maximum of 3200 Tweets (in 200 Tweets per “page”). To retrieve more, you would need to use the premium or enterprise full archive search API.